# Creating tree structure objects from file paths with Cocoa-Touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a list of documents and their paths.

```
Unsigned/Corporate Tax Return/Testing.docx
Signed/Report/fieldsInfo.pdf
Unsigned/Corporate Tax Return/testSecure.pdf
Unsigned/Corporate Tax Return/2012/fileCatcher.pdf
Unsigned/Corporate Tax Return/2012/taxReturn.pdf
```

From this i want a tree structured object array where all these object are placed in.
I have two objecttypes: Document and File

How would i go about doing this in objective C ?

what i had so far:

```
- (void) createFolderStructure:(Document *) doc{
    Folder * root = [[Folder alloc]init];

    NSArray * folders = [doc.documentFilePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    for(NSString * folderName in folders){
        if([root.folderSubFolders count] == 0){
            //root is empty , create folder
            Folder * newFolder = [[Folder alloc]init];
            newFolder.folderName = folderName;
            [root.folderSubFolders addObject:newFolder];
        } else {
            //root has subfolders
            for(Folder * folder in root.folderSubFolders){
                if ([folder.folderName isEqualToString:folderName]) {
                    //folder exists in subfolders

                } else {
                    //folder doesn't exist ,create folder
                    Folder * newFolder = [[Folder alloc]init];
                    newFolder.folderName = folderName;
                    [root.folderSubFolders addObject:newFolder];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
NSString *str = @"Unsigned/Corporate Tax Return/2012/taxReturn.pdf";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

So then you have an array contains NSStrings

0 - Unsigned, 1 - Corporate Tax Return...

When you do this:

```
id fileObj = [arr lastObject];
```

You will get *File* object, rest of the objects in array should be *Document* objects.